# apache mod_proxy redirections not working properly

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I have small servlet app started on port 8081.

I made reverse proxy via apache mod_proxy like this:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyVia On

ProxyPass /my_app/ http://localhost:8081/
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:8081 /my_app

<Location /my_app/>
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /my_app/
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>
</IfModule>
```

The problem here is if I sand redirect from my app eg. form /exp1 to /exp2 browser will be redirected from /my_app/exp1 to /exp2 instead to /my_app/exp2.

How can I tell mod_proxy to prepend /my_app/ on every redirect requests.